# Oracle aggregate for joining strings with comma, and about writing custom aggregates

Tags: oracle, function, aggregate-functions

How can i create a function on Oracle like sum, min, max?

it will run on result set.

```
Select join(',', Name), sum(total) From Account Group By IdCity
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: Way to aggregate concatenate an ungrouped column in grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757394/oracle-way-to-aggregate-concatenate-an-ungrouped-column-in-grouped-results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a link to the documentation that describes how you can create your own aggregate functions: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/aggr_functions.htm

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 3):

Use `wmsys.wm_concat` if Oracle version is 10 or more.

You can also do a lookup on [creating aggregate functions](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/agg_fun.html) in Oracle.

Note that SQLite has the `group_concat` builtin aggregate if maybe you were interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [listagg function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm). It's a solution to your problem (although it doesn't describe how to build your own aggregate function).