# SQL SELECT group multiple rows together when LISTAGG and WM_CONCAT are not available

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble explaining this, so if someone can make adjustments to the title or question then please do.

I have a simple SQL query that I'm running

```
SELECT orders.customer_no, orders.order_no FROM orders WHERE orders.creation = '01-JAN-14';
```

resulting in

```
customer_no   order_no
----------- ----------
         0    8051729
         2    2809137
         2    3794827
         3    1934678
         3    9237192
         6    3462890
         6    3131378
         6    6267190
         6    2864952
         6    1325645
```

but what I want is

```
customer_no   order_no
----------- ----------
         0    8051729
         2    2809137 3794827
         3    1934678 9237192
         6    3462890 3131378 6267190 2864952 1325645
```

Is it possible to do something like this direct within SQL?

**Edit:** Using Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select orders.customer_no, listagg(orders.order_no, ' ') within group (order by orders.order_no) orders.order_no
  from orders 
  WHERE orders.creation = '01-JAN-14'
  group by orders.customer_no;
```

In MySQL you would want the GROUP_CONCAT function, which is roughly LISTAGG in Oracle, according to:

[Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql)

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`. I'm looking at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#SQLRF51487 but can't see what I'm doing wrong. Your SQL seems good.

Comment: Apparently LISTAGG is only available from 11g, what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Ah, I'm on a server running Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - Production. I'll update the question with that detail. Sorry about that.

Comment: But it isn't complaining about an undefined function LISTAGG? I think maybe I got the group and where the wrong way round, try the updated question

Comment: I tried the updated answer but still getting `ORA-00923` and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569633/oracle-sql-listagg-function `ORA-00923` seems like a reasonable error message when `LISTAGG` is not available. So ... is there an alternative? :-)

Comment: Just a note that I've also tried `WM_CONCAT` but that also isn't available on this version.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Oracle: Way to aggregate concatenate an ungrouped column in grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757394/oracle-way-to-aggregate-concatenate-an-ungrouped-column-in-grouped-results), you can try something like:

```
WITH j
     AS (SELECT customer_no, order_no
           FROM orders
          WHERE creation = '01-JAN-14')
SELECT   RTRIM (
            EXTRACT (SYS_XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ("X", order_no || ' ')), '/ROWSET/X/text()').getstringval (),
            ', ')
    FROM j
GROUP BY customer_no;
```